# Information schema, how to retrieve link tables

Tags: database-design

I'm wokring on a script that can create a data vault based on a database. To identify all the hubs i need a query that gives me the name of the link tables (many-to-many).

what is the best way to do this:

find surrogate keys or do I have to analyse the relations where they come from and where they go to?

Thank you in afvanced

Answer (score 1):

In a many-to-many, you can count on the existence of foreign keys.  You can't count on the existence of surrogate keys.

At the very least, I think you'll need to identify tables that have

- either a compound primary key or
- a compound unique constraint

together with at least two columns that have foreign key references to other tables.

If your platform supports information_schema views, you'll probably need to look at one or more of these.

- information_schema.key_column_usage
- information_schema.referential_constraints
- information_schema.table_constraints

I think this will give you the tables that have a compound primary key in PostgreSQL.  Might help get you started.

```
select t.constraint_name, t.table_name, count(*) num_key_columns
from information_schema.table_constraints t
inner join information_schema.key_column_usage k 
    on (t.constraint_name = k.constraint_name)
where t.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' or t.constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'
group by t.constraint_name, t.table_name
having count(*) >= 2;
```

(If I were doing this, I'd create a view from this query. Another for foreign key references. Joins on them should be dead simple.)